# Serializers available in .NET

Tags: .net

I'm trying to broaden my knowledge about the available .net serializers. I came up with the following list, but i guess i'm missing some:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer
System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer
System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer
Custom Serialization
```

Could somebody point me or provide a complete list of serializers available in .NET 4.8? Or at least those that brings value to an advanced developer ...

Comment: There are  A LOT of serializers. Answers to this question will get outdated fast. Thus voting to close. Just google ".net serializer"

Comment: @jgauffin I disagree that the list will get outdated fast. Most are since the dawn of the .net and core related serializers has been added at a slow pace.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure this doesn't qualify as a complete list, but anytime i'm looking to broaden my knowledge of anything, I make sure to check out some Github awesome-xxx lists.

For .NET this could be for example : https://github.com/quozd/awesome-dotnet#serialization

Comment: Nice, but these are external libraries i'm not asking for.

Comment: Well then I guess the .NET documentation will have everything you need. And it should be well up to date.